# Baked texture not same with cycles render preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking

HDRI seems the main cause of this, but how can I achieve the cycles render look on my baked texture?

[image: Cycles Render Preview]

[image: Baked texture]

Comment: Do you mean that you've baked the texture but it doesn't take the HDRI into account?

Comment: kinda, but it only happens on white or greyish texture, don't have a problem on other colors

Comment: do your grey material have metallic?

Comment: no sir, only specular and roughness (principle bdsf)

Comment: maybe pack your images and only share one part (with the grey color)? https://blend-exchange.com/